# Eclipse doesn't encode characters properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, eclipse, encoding

So I'm trying to use Nordic characters in Python using Eclipse.
I'm aware of the declaration you can do in the beginning of the code but it would be great (and easier) to find a default settings for this since I'll probably use a lot of my native language in all my programs.

I went both to Preferences > General > Workspace and General > Content type and changed my default encoding to "ISO-8859-1" used in the Nordics but still the console says I use non-ASCII characters and it doesnt work.

1. Am I missing some setting or is it safe to say I need to declare the encoding every time in the beginning?
2. Even when I declare the encoding in my code, the 'printed' output still is very weird and doesnt show the non-ASCII characters properly and has weird spacing issues. Any idea what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not keep UTF-8? It's better. Also, what's your OS?

Comment: Thx for your response!
Unfortunately, that doesnt work either despite it being the default setting.
I have OSX 10.14

Comment: CAn you give an example of code with such characters? And I suggest to revert the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Done! UTF-8 should work!

I want to write "ÅÄÖ" 
Console without declaration: yntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file *** but no encoding declared; 

With declaration, it just writes the letters like '\xc3 \xc5 test test"..

Comment: You mean in python console inside Eclipse? Also, which python plugin ar u using?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse's console.
I'm using PyDev and have the 3.9 version of Python on my comp.

Answer (score 0):

Console encoding can be checked with

```
>>> import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))
/usr/bin/python3 3.6.12 (default, Dec 02 2020, 09:44:23) [GCC]

>>> print("stdin encoding : {}\nstdout endoding: {}".format(sys.stdin.encoding,sys.stdout.encoding ))
stdin encoding : UTF-8
stdout endoding: UTF-8
>>> a = u'ÅÄÖ'
>>> print(a)
ÅÄÖ
>>> print(chr(195),chr(196),chr(197))
Ã Ä Å
```

For PyDev, console encoding is set at

> Preferences -> Interactive console -> Encoding for interactive console

Comment: It's UTF-8 but still it doesnt support the Nordic letters when i run the program with a simple 'print' function...

Comment: Did u tried my answer as is? What's the default encoding on your OS?

Comment: Try also `print(chr(195),chr(196),chr(197))`

Comment: Output: ('\xc3', '\xc4', '\xc5')

System encoding is UTF-8 on my Mac

Comment: so the encoding is still `ISO-8859-1` somewhere in the config. what do you get from `print("stdin encoding : {}\nstdout endoding: {}".format(sys.stdin.encoding,sys.stdout.encoding ))`

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..../... .py", line 7, in <module>
    print("stdin encoding : {}\nstdout endoding: {}".format(sys.stdin.encoding, sys.stdout.encoding))
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined"

Hmm this is new... appreciate you helping out!

Comment: you are missing the imports mentioned in my answer: `import sys; print('%s %s' % (sys.executable or sys.platform, sys.version))`

Comment: So this is the output i get

/usr/bin/python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 25 2021, 18:52:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)]
stdin encoding : UTF-8
stdout endoding: UTF-8

Still, when i insert the latter part of your answer, i get the same non-ASCII letter error.... very weird.