# Eclipse doesn't allow the rendering of greek characters in the console

Tags: java, eclipse

If I try to output any greek character `αΑβΒγΓδΔεΕζΖηΗθΘιΙκΚλΛμΜνΝξΞοΟπΠρΡςΣτΤυΥφΦχΧψΨωΩ` to the Eclipse console (sysout), it gets replaced by a questionmark `?`.

- Im using Eclipse 2022-03
- I have enabled UTF-8 in each of the following settings:

  - `Run As -> Run configurations -> Common -> Encoding`
  - `Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> Text`
  - `Preferences -> Workspace -> Text file encoding`
- Console Font: Consolas (default / works in the text-editor)
- Operating System: Windows 11

Also: When I try to render `äöüÄÖÜß` with UTF-8, it gives the `�`-character. (This can be fixed by enabling `ISO-859-1` under `Run As -> Run configurations -> Common -> Encoding`)

Comment: With what Console Font? Not every one supports every character that fits in UTF-8.

Comment: @nitind Consolas. It works also in the regular editor, so that cannot be the problem. Also: if I write the Strings to a File, they also get saved correctly.

Comment: You're using Consolas as your basic Text Font, too?

Comment: @xtay2 how do you write to the console and what operating system do you have?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/68900204/2834978

Comment: *Also: When I try to render äöüÄÖÜß with UTF-8, it gives the �-character. (This can be fixed by using ISO-859-1)* Well of course none of those characters is Greek ;) But what do you mean by "by using"? *How* do you use it?

Comment: @rmunge System.out.println in Windows 11 (10.0.22000)

Comment: @g00se Enabling it under `Run As -> Run configurations -> Common -> Encoding`. I just find it odd, because UTF8 should support them.

Comment: I suspect your file is not encoded as UTF-8, in which case, saying it is won't help. I can't say that for sure though without seeing an *actual* source file. You could make one, with the `main` method just printing a failing string and then link to it if you want. Windows machines haven't really moved on from 7/8 bit encodings under the hood afaics. What does `chcp` at the command line give?

Comment: On my system when I try to do sysout with above mentioned characters, before saving, it is asking me to save file in UTF-8 format & then after that it executes properly. Eclipse version : 2021-12

Comment: @g00se chcp returns 850, and the file is definitly encoded it UTF-8 as it can display the symbols. The problem lies only with the console.

Comment: cp850 will not have *any* Greek characters. If you do chcp 65001 before you run your code, you should be OK if the source code is OK

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried ISO-8859-7 instead of UTF-8 and my problem was solved.

Comment: After years looking for the right answer!!!! THANKS!